# how to program for a click event of a listbox control when the .name property is unknown at design time

Tags: vb.net, events, listbox, click, runtime

I have an application that has several forms.
On one of those forms I have an empty tab control.
At runtime, The user enters a string into a textbox.
That string is used to create a new tab using that string as its .text property
and also, a listbox gets created on that new tab with it's .name property also the same name as the string the user entered.

So Starts with empty tabcontrol
User enters string
New tab is created with string as its name
New Listbox is created and New list with the string as their names.

Then a wizard fires and asks questions to the user, the answers to which are stored into a string array and then concatenated into one long string which is added to the list box.

I have the tabs, listbox, and listitems saved on exit and replaced on load.

Now when a user double clicks the listbox item, I want to show a dialog using the string in the list to display the data.

HOWEVER and here is my problem:
Every tab and List has a .name property that was assigned by whatever the user input into that text box.

So lets say it was "Taxi"
I have a tab on the control named Taxi tabcontrol1.tabpage.item(0) = "Taxi"
and a listbox contol on that tab with the .name property of Taxi
so Taxi.item(0) would be the first list item in taxi which is a listbox control

But since I programatically created those .name property's at runtime,
How can I now address the listbox.name property to write code behind the click event of the listbox's item member?

```
'industry is the user inputted string
        TabControl1.TabPages.Add(industry)
        TabControl1.Refresh()
        TabControl1.SelectedTab = TabControl1.TabPages.Item(industry)
        TabControl1.Parent = Me.ActiveControl.Parent
        Dim newListbox As New System.Windows.Forms.ListBox
        Dim locationpoint As Point
        newListbox.Parent = TabControl1.SelectedTab
        newListbox.Width = 1154
        newListbox.Height = 498
        locationpoint.X = 0
        locationpoint.Y = 0
        newListbox.Location = locationpoint
        newListbox.Name = industry
        newListbox.BorderStyle = BorderStyle.Fixed3D
        newListbox.CreateControl()
        Dim counttabs = TabControl1.TabCount
        TabControl1.SelectedIndex = counttabs
        Me.TabControl1.SelectTab(counttabs - 1)
        TabControl1.SelectedTab.Controls.Add(newListbox)
        newListbox.Dock = DockStyle.Top
        TabControl1.SelectTab(industry)
```

Comment: You need to use the `AddHandler` statement to add the click event handler for your `ListBox`.  Inside your handler, the `sender` argument is the `ListBox` that was clicked.

Comment: That was more greek than vb to me

Comment: Could you please describe that to me in code?

Comment: I get it a little I think. I will create a handler for a click event of a listbox and somehow tell the handler to handle any listbox on the tab?

Comment: Also after reading up... It looks like if I do what you are suggesting, If I understand the syntax, I'd have to use a handles clause pointing to the listbox and the problem is I can't address by any means that I am aware of that list box's list item when the user clicks or ideally double clicks a item in the list box.  Right now it is taxi.items(0) but it could be dentist.items(0) there is no way for me to know what the user will name the tab and ultimately name the listbox.name property of the listbox that gets placed in the tab at runtime.

Comment: You don't need the name. Add an event handler to `Listbox.SelectedIndexChange`, for example: `AddHandler newListbox.SelectedIndexChange, AddressOf Me.ListIndexChanged`. Add the delegate:   `Private Sub ListIndexChanged(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Dim currentListBox as ListBox = DirectCast(sender, ListBox) Dim clickedText = currentListBox.GetItemText(currentListBox.SelectedItem) End Sub`. Remove this line: `TabControl1.Parent = Me.ActiveControl.Parent` and this one: `newListbox.CreateControl()`. The other properties' declarations can be simplified.

Comment: You were told to use the `AddHandler` statement.  What's stopping you typing "vb.net addhandler" into Google?  If you expect to be an anywhere decent programmer then your first thought when you hear a new term has to be to search for it on the web and read. Not surprisingly, the first search result is the documentation and it shows you how to use it.

Comment: When using `AddHandler`, you _don't_ use the `Handles` keyword.  `Handles` only works when you create the control at design time.

Comment: Jimi This WORKED!

Comment: jmcilhinney im sorry im not the programming god!

Comment: comments like that serve no purpose. I obviously googled it and studied and didn't understand. in fact, Jimi had the answer and even with the code in front of my face I didn't get what was being said and worked on this issue for the last two days. I finally understand now. my point is sarcasm or nasty attitudes aren't constructive

Comment: Chris thanks for your help as well.

Comment: I am now trying to get it to work on a double click rather than on selection as on load the first item is autoselected and therefore triggers the event but I know how to code around that if needbe... but it makes more sense to have it perform the function on the mouse double click event. Im sure ill figure that out shortly.

Comment: i tried to change   ```AddHandler newListbox.SelectedIndexChange, AddressOf Me.ListIndexChanged```

Comment: to :    ```AddHandler newListbox.MouseDoubleClick, AddressOf Me.ListIndexChanged```

Comment: That didn't do it though

Comment: It was just .doubleclick instead of .MouseDoubleClick.

Answer (score 0):

Here's an example that creates `ListBox` controls at run time and wires up their `MouseClick` event using `AddHandler`.  The same event handler is used for all the controls.  The `sender` argument is used get the `ListBox` that was clicked and then to display it's name.  You will need to create a Windows Form with a single button named Button1.

```
Public Class Form1

    Private yPos As Integer = 50
    Private listBoxNumber As Integer = 1

    Private Sub Button1_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click

        'Create the ListBox
        Dim lb As New ListBox()

        'Set properties
        lb.Location = New Point(50, yPos)
        lb.Height = 25
        lb.Width = 100
        lb.Name = $"ListBox{listBoxNumber}"

        'Wire up the Event Handler
        AddHandler lb.MouseClick, AddressOf ListBox_MouseClick

        'Add to the Form
        Me.Controls.Add(lb)

        'Update yPos and list box Number
        yPos += 30
        listBoxNumber += 1

    End Sub

    Private Sub ListBox_MouseClick(sender As Object, e As MouseEventArgs)

        'Get the ListBox that was clicked from the sender argument
        Dim lb As ListBox = DirectCast(sender, ListBox)

        'Display its name
        MessageBox.Show($"ListBox with name ""{lb.Name}"" was clicked!")

    End Sub

    Private Sub Button2_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button2.Click

        'Search for controls with a specific name.  
        'This returns an array
        Dim controlsFound = Me.Controls.Find("ListBox2", False)

        If (controlsFound.Any()) Then
            Dim lb As ListBox = DirectCast(controlsFound(0), ListBox)

            MessageBox.Show("Found the control!")

            'Get the selected Items or whatever here


        Else
            MessageBox.Show("Control not found.")
        End If
    End Sub

End Class
```

Comment: I'll study this for a second and see what I can understand and implement.

Comment: In reading the code I have a couple of questions: 1.Is this all just to accomplish clicking anywhere on the list box and having a msgbox tell me the name of the control? That is what I am reading this code does. If I am wrong please tell me. That isn't what i'm trying to accomplish.
I can find the name of the listbox control a lot easier than that if thats the case.
I could be completely off though on what im reading here...
I need to be able to click on a specific item in the list control and have it return the item that was clicked. which im sure I can code.

Comment: The problem is I can't seem to figure out how to address that listbox if the name of the control is dynamic.
I hope i'm being clear and if your answer accomplishes this goal then my appologies it didn't seem like that is what it did. to me it looks like your code returns the listbox .name property when the listbox is clicked anywhere...
is that so?

Comment: I mean ultimately i'm looking to address the item member of the listbox that was clicked or double clicked but being able just to get to the control itself is enough i can work with its members after I can reference it.

Comment: Previously in my application, in the function that saves the list members to the registry or retrieval at frm load I was able to reference the list like this For Each ctrl As Control In TabControl1.TabPages.Item(0).Controls If TypeOf ctrl Is ListBox Then If DirectCast(ctrl, ListBox).Name = industry Then End If   but that is when i wanted to assign the name of the string variable the tab and the list was named to the element in the registry. the variable name at that point is known... "industry" . at next run industry is "" and holds the string variable entered by the user at runtime.

Comment: What if:
When the user inputs the string variable "industry" I can save that variable
to either the registry or settings. Then when retriving the tabs list controls
and list items, I can also recall this variable which will then have the name 
of the tab and the name of the listbox control. But and here is my question...
How can I reference a string in a variable as a control name...
So in psudo code:
   ```'my.settings.industry = "Taxi"
savedIndustry = my.settings.industry
now I want Taxi.items(0).text
How can I basically do this:
savedIndustry.items(0).text  ```

Comment: That would solve my problem
obviously doesn't work that way but there has
to be a very easy way I am unaware of to use a 
variable's value as a control name.... no?

Comment: If you've assigned a name, you could search the controls collection by name.  See the update.  I've added button2 to search for a control by name.  This searches the Form's Controls collection.  For a `TabPage` you use the tab page instead of `Me`

Comment: Awesome! I didn't try it yet but I understand it.

Comment: Thank you i'll let you know how it works out for sure!

Answer (score 0):

```
AddHandler newListbox.SelectedIndexChange, AddressOf Me.ListIndexChanged
Private Sub ListIndexChanged(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) 
Dim currentListBox as ListBox = DirectCast(sender, ListBox) 
Dim clickedText = currentListBox.GetItemText(currentListBox.SelectedItem) 
End Sub.
```

Adding that code to mine as presented in my question did what I needed to accomplish
I also, (as instructed) deleted the line that assigned the tab control as the list's parent and removed the line about creating the listbox control
The correct answer was submitted by Jimi although Chris may have had another way to accomplish this... I just couldn't figure it out.